# Why does setInterval initiate when I'm only assigning it?

Tags: javascript

I'm assigning to a variable, a function that uses setInterval, but I don't want the function to run until I call it. However, the function is running from just the assignment statement.

```
sessionClock = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hi")
}, 1000)
```

I have also tried like this:

```
sayHi = function() {
  console.log("Hi");
}

var sayHiStarter = setInterval(sayHi, 1000);
```

Both of these initiate the function and will log "Hi" to the console.

Why is it running on assignment? And what can do I do fix this?

Comment: It does exactly that. But it does it before I call the function. I thought the code I posted is only an assignment, but yet the code is still initiated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you only want to bind a function to setInterval, but call it later, you can use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```js
var sessionClock = setInterval.bind(null, function() {
  console.log("Hi")
}, 1000);

//... later

var myInterval = sessionClock(); // start the timer

// ... later if you need to clear it

clearInterval(myInterval);
```

In principle, bind returns a new function that calls your original function (in this case, `setInterval`) with predefined arguments. So when you call `sessionClock`, that returned function is called. There a other aspects to `bind`, but they don't seem to apply in this context.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, that works perfectly! Will accept as answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: This is working, but if I need to turn the function on and off multiple times, it seems like multiple instances of the function are triggered. So instead of "Hi" being logged once a second, it will be logged many times per second(if I turn the function on and off many times). I know this has something to do with the ID but I can't figure out how to prevent this from happening.

Comment: You shouldn't have more than one "instance" of sessionClock at a time. So once you don't need the first "instance" anymore, stop it first with `clearInterval` (using a reference variable such as `myInterval`). Only then start the second one. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: You are correct, and that is what I'm doing. I use `myInterval` as a reference for `clearInterval` and it does stop the current "instance". But let's say I want to resume the 'sessionClock' function, does it create an entirely new instance? I thought setInterval and clearInterval could almost be used like pause and resume buttons, but maybe not?

Comment: `setInterval` is more like an infinite loop (although it does not block other code execution, as it runs asynchronously), and `clearInterval` stops that loop. So every time you call `setInterval` again, you create a new "loop".

Comment: I see. OK, I think I'm starting to get it. Thanks for your time and responses!

Answer (score 1):

The call to `setInterval` does not return a function, but an identification for the created interval. This id is used to remove the interval when you don't want it to execute anymore:

```
sessionClock = setInterval(function() {
  console.log("Hi")
}, 1000)

...

clearInterval(sessionclock);
```

What you want is something like this:

```
sessionClock = function () {
  return setInterval(function() {
      console.log("Hi")
    },
 1000);
}

//When needed
var intervalId=sessionClock();
```

Comment: Good to know. I've had a hard time understanding the ID that setInterval returns, but this helps. Thanks!